# Excel If cell is empty want to move data from another cell

Tags: excel, formula

I wish to check if a cell in say column A  is empty and if it is then move the data from the next column B into it.  Else nothing done.
I wish it to check 1500 rows. I tried

If(A2="",A2=B2,"")  I thought I could just copy it down the column.  I get a circular error reference and also then cellA2 changes to 0.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll need to do this on a "helper column", unless you want VBA. In, say `C2`, put this formula, `=IF($A2="",$B2,$A2)` and drag down. Then copy column C and paste **as values** over column A.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a one-time task, merging two columns of data, or something that needs to be run repeatedly?

Your formula won't work (partly) because you can't have a cell that contains both a value **and** a formula (to check that value), at the same time.

You could, however have a 3rd column that equals `Column A`, unless `Column A` is *blank*, in which case it looks at `Column B`.

With your example, in cell `C2` you could put:

```
=If(A2="",B2,A2)
```

With your formula above, you're trying assign a value to A2 with `A2=B2`.  Excel formulas in cells assign values to "themselves" and cannot directly affect other cells.

A formula in A2 can only affect the A2. (However, the *value* of a cell can *indirectly* affect other cells with the help of VBA or features like Conditional Formatting.)

The reason your `If` statement isn't giving you an error with `A2=B2` is because that statement `A2=B2` is **comparing** the value of cell A2 to B2 and returning `TRUE` if the cells match, and FALSE if they do not (so will always return **`FALSE`** in this case).

Comment: Thank you, It is making sense now. I thought that  A2=B2 would assign to B2  if A2="" were true. Must think about it. I will make a new field to stop the  circular reference. I will look up conditional Formatting.

Comment: I only need this for a one time thing. I wanted to just drag a formula field down the whole column for 1400 records.

Comment: I used the If (a2="",B2,A2)  It is brilliant and simple. Thank you Ashleedawg